# android - manipulating the 'share' menu

Tags: android, api, menu

first off - let me just say that I am NOT asking how to *implement* a share button in my app or anything like that. I know all about using Intents and Intent Filters etc etc.

what I AM asking about is this: is there any way to get access to the "Share" *menu* itself? in other words, I'd love to build an app that filters out some of the services I never use but that I don't want to delete from my phone completely.

I tried looking it up in the Android API, but only found info on getting your app to show up in the menu or putting a 'Share' button in your app etc.

Being that I'm still somewhat of a novice programmer, I'm also wondering if there's some way for me to sniff out the API objects that are being created/used when the 'Share' menu is built/displayed? Seems like I could do it in a Debugger session, but I'm not sure how.

Thank you in advance.
b

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are two ways to go around Share menu. First one is to use

```
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(Intent, CharSequence)
```

But in this case, I am not sure how to obtain an access to the created share menu, coz it is a separate activity.
However, if you wish to have a control over the list of share items being displayed for your app, there is another way to approach your share menu item implementation.
Take a look at this code snippet:

```
//Prepare an intent to filter the activities you need
//Add a List<YourItemType> where you going to store the share-items
List<YourItemType> myShareList = new List<YourItemType>;

PackageManager packageManager = mContext.getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> activities = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
int numActivities = activities.size();

for (int i = 0; i != numActivities; ++i) {
    final ResolveInfo info = activities.get(i);
    String label = info.loadLabel(packageManager).toString();

    //now you can check label or some other info and decide whether to add the item
    //into your own list of share items

    //Every item in your list should have a runnable which will execute
    // proper share-action (Activity)
  myShareList.add(new YourItemType(label, info.loadIcon(packageManager), new Runnable() 
     {
       public void run() {
           startResolvedActivity(intent, info);
       }
 }));

}
```

This code snippet shows how to get a list of the activities which are able to process share request. What you need to do next is to show your own UI. It is up to you what you are going to choose.

Comment: thanks Alex, that's valuable information - but I think I wasn't completely clear on what I'm trying to do. I'm not looking to filter 'Share' items in just MY app - I'd like to filter them on in ALL apps!
I'm guessing its probably impossible since each app implements the share menu inside it's own sandbox, but I what I was hoping for is for there to be some kind of hook for the 'Share' menu items built in to the system API that would allow me to filter and combine the items that show up in that list - again for *every* app.

Comment: also - I know that in ICS you can implement code *within* your own app that will cause your more frequently used items to float to the top of the 'Share' menu... so I got to thinking that maybe there was some way to access it's properties directly.

Comment: Ahh, I see. I misunderstood your "build an app that filters out some of the services I never use". Well, can't be sure on this one, because I never tried it myself. But if the list is generated dynamically based on the information from package manager (which I believe is the case), the only way I see to manipulate the share list globally is to work PackageManager. However, briefly looked into its APIs, I don't see how to achieve your goal.
Regarding the ICS thing: it sounds interesting - can you give me a link or something?

Comment: gladly - I noticed it on my new Galaxy Nexus, so I looked it up and found the section "Ice Cream Sandwich makes it even easier" about 1/2 down the page at http://android-developers.blogspot.com/  the API link (provided in the blog post) is here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ShareActionProvider.html  I haven't used it yet... but from a user's perspective it's pretty cool. not quite as cool as filtering or grouping would be ;-) but still pretty cool.